# Why jquery signature does not run on my mobile ? on my desktop work great

Tags: jquery-mobile, oracle-apex

S.O. Guys!.

i got an Oracle Apex screen, where customers will digitally sign. The app is in jQuery Mobile Smartphone User Interface, but when i try to call the page on a tablet or smartphone it just hang and does not display the page. so i tried running it over mozila firefox on my dektop and runs ok.

here is my code, i hope you can comment something about the issue.
thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Signature Basics</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.kbw-signature { width: 600px; height: 250px; }
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#libraries/jquery/1.7.1/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#libraries/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="#IMAGE_PREFIX#libraries/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.signature.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#libraries/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.signature.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
    $('#defaultSignature').signature({guideline: true, guidelineOffset: 25, guidelineIndent: 20, guidelineColor: '#ff0000'});
        $('#defaultSignature').signature({syncField: '#signatureJSON'}); 

        $('#removeSignature').click
          (
           function() 
             { 
               $('#defaultSignature').signature({syncField: '#signatureJSON'}); 
               $('#defaultSignature').signature('destroy');
               $('#defaultSignature').signature({guideline: true, guidelineOffset: 25, guidelineIndent: 20, guidelineColor: '#ff0000'});
               $('#defaultSignature').signature({syncField: '#signatureJSON'}); 
              }
          ); 

        $('#disableSignature').toggle
          (
           function() 
             { 
               $s("P60_FIRMA",$v("signatureJSON" ));
               $(this).text('Editar Firma'); 
               $('#defaultSignature').signature('disable'); 
               $('#removeSignature').attr("disabled", true);
             }, 
           function() 
             { 
               $x("P60_FIRMA").value = null;
               $(this).text('Finalizar Firma'); 
               $('#defaultSignature').signature('enable'); 
               $('#removeSignature').attr("disabled", false);
             }
           );
}
);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="defaultSignature"></div>
<p style="clear: both;">
<button type="button" style="font-weight: bold; width: auto;" id="removeSignature">Limpiar Firma</button> <button type="button" style="font-weight: bold; width: auto;" id="disableSignature">Finalizar Firma</button><p><span class="demoLabel"></span><textarea id="signatureJSON" rows="1" cols="1" style="display:none;"></textarea></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and [found](http://keith-wood.name/signature.html) the following solution:

> If you are using the plugin on a touch-enabled device, you might also want to download and include the jQuery UI [Touch Punch](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js) plugin:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: This works but the size of the signature box should not flow out of the ui and this js file should be locally available.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the furf website, but the code there hasn't been updated since 2014 (8 years now) and it didn't work. I did discover a newer fork that works perfectly. Here is the link https://github.com/RWAP/jquery-ui-touch-punch

I know this is an old post, however I needed a signature block that would allow me to save the signature on the server-side, not the client.

My PHP application is an equipment sign-out sheet that queries an MSSQL database for equipment that is assigned to an employee. It then goes through a conditions sheet (terms of use, etc.) and finally to a sign out page. A final PDF is compiled and saved then inserted into the appropriate employee folder.